# How to center flex block in center page?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have `div block` with property `flex` CSS.

This block has 80% width and 50% height of display.

How to display this block in center by horizontal and vertical?

Comment: Use properties justify-content: center; and align-items:center;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex alignment properties apply to the children of a flex container.

So if you have a div with `display: flex`, and you want to center this div, you make the parent a flex container. Then you can apply flex alignment properties to the div.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here's a more complete explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: Why add an answer if a similar question was already answered earlier and you've even linked it? This should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The only difference is that the flex wrapper is body instead of a wrapping div. This really doesn't deserve a separate question/answer.

Comment: I didn't mark as a duplicate because most of those posts deal with centering flex items. This particular question asked about centering a flex container. I felt a more clear explanation would be useful to the OP.

Comment: So, it works only when to set `flex` to body

Comment: Flex layout works only between parent and child. If you want to center an element using flex properties, make the parent a flex container.